# gcc reporting "incomplete type" errors when using OpenMP with templated types

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm currently getting errors when trying to build the following code with gcc. I've tried both v10 and v11 with the same result.

I can't for the life of me figure out why gcc doesn't accept it. clang++ compiles it perfectly happily.

```cpp
class MyClass {
    int val = 0;
};

template<class T>
void fun()
{
    static T obj;
    #pragma omp threadprivate(obj)
}

int main()
{
    fun<MyClass>();
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
openmp_test.cc: In function ‘void fun()’:
openmp_test.cc:9:35: error: ‘threadprivate’ ‘obj’ has incomplete type
    9 |     #pragma omp threadprivate(obj)
      |                                   ^
```

Comment: Appears to be https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27557, which contains a workaround of sorts

Comment: @AlexF the ``#pragma omp`` is not a pre-processor directive. It is an OpenMP directive and should be type aware. https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu104.html